# Segmentation fault in Python with multiprocessing calls to Dialogflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, segmentation-fault, multiprocessing, dialogflow-es

I'm struggling to understand why the code below leads to a segmentation fault.

It appears to be non-deterministic, to occur about 30% of times and I noticed it doesn't happen if I replace processes with threads. (But I need processes in my particular application).

The code below is an attempt to isolate the error from a large project (which was super hard to do), so please notice there might be parts that seem illogical or incomplete, and I also added some lines to increase the chances of error (like repeating something multiple times).

In order to run the code, please use your own Dialogflow credentials and set the variables `PROJECT_ID`, `AGENT_NAME` and `DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID` accordingly.

I'm using **Python 3.8** with the packages **google-api-core==2.0.1**, **google-auth==2.2.2**, **google-cloud-dialogflow==2.7.1**.

```py
import faulthandler
import os
import shutil
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

import google.cloud.dialogflow as dialogflow

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'credentials.json'  # USE YOUR OWN
SESSION_ID = '0' 
PROJECT_ID = '####'    # USE YOUR OWN
AGENT_NAME = '####'    # USE YOUR OWN
DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = '###'    # USE YOUR OWN

session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)

faulthandler.enable(all_threads=True)

os.makedirs('dir_foo', exist_ok=True)
shutil.make_archive(f'agent_foo', 'zip', f'dir_foo')  # Make an empty zip file (mock agent)


def create_agent(language):
    print('Creating agent', AGENT_NAME)

    parent = "projects/" + PROJECT_ID
    agents_client = dialogflow.AgentsClient()

    agent = dialogflow.Agent(
        parent=parent, display_name=AGENT_NAME, default_language_code=language, time_zone="GMT"
    )

    print('Creating new agent')
    agents_client.set_agent(request={"agent": agent})

    return agents_client


def upload_bot(language):
    for i in range(5):
        agent = create_agent(language)
        encoded_string = open(f"agent_foo.zip", "rb").read()

    request = {
        "parent": f'projects/{PROJECT_ID}',
        "agent_content": encoded_string
    }
    print('Uploading...')
    for i in range(5):
        agent.restore_agent(request)
    print('Successfully updated bot!')


def execute():
    try:
        upload_bot('en')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


processes_list = list()
for i in range(16):
    t = Process(target=execute)
    t.start()
    processes_list.append(t)
    sleep(1)

for c in range(len(processes_list)):
    processes_list[c].join()

print('DONE')
```

Here's the error message:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x00007f78a0d91740 (most recent call first):
File "#/.envs/project-name-3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 933 in _blocking
File "#/.envs/project-name-3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 944 in __call__
File "#/.envs/project-name-3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 66 in error_remapped_callable
File "#/.envs/project-name-3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 142 in __call__
File "#/.envs/project-name-3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/dialogflow_v2/services/agents/client.py", line 511 in set_agent
File "#/bm/project-name/DEBUG_segfault.py", line 35 in create_agent
File "#/bm/project-name/DEBUG_segfault.py", line 42 in upload_bot
File "#/bm/project-name/DEBUG_segfault.py", line 57 in execute
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108 in run
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 313 in _bootstrap
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 75 in _launch
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19 in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 276 in _Popen
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224 in _Popen
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121 in start
File "#/bm/project-name/DEBUG_segfault.py", line 65 in <module>'
```

Comment: This looks like a `google-cloud-dialogflow` issue. Can you [report a bug](https://github.com/googleapis/python-dialogflow/issues/new/choose)?

Comment: @Marat I'll do that.

Comment: Has this issue happened always? or something temporary?